# Why do I get ERR_ACCESS_DENIED when submitting a form that includes an uploaded file using Capybara with Selenium's Chrome driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have feature tests for a Rails app that currently work when the driver is set to [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist). I'm trying to switch from Poltergeist to Selenium (using Chrome as the browser) but get an error when submitting a form that includes an uploaded file...

Here's what the test is trying to do:

```rb
attach_file "Choose file", Rails.root.join('spec','support','dummy_documents','dummy_document_1.docx'), make_visible: true
click_on 'Update'
```

Capybara finds the 'dummy_document_1.docx' file and successfully adds it to the file field. But when the form is submitted (by clicking 'Update'), the request to the server fails before being sent and I see this error :
[image: err_access_denied error]

Here's the Selenium driver setup - note that I'm already disabling Chrome extensions:

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  browser_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

My `chromedriver` version is `ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912})` and my Chrome version is `Version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (x86_64)`.

Also note:

- The same form submits successfully if I don't attach a file
- The error doesn't happen when setting the driver to `selenium` or `selenium_headless` (i.e. using Firefox instead of chrome) or when setting the browser to `safari` (with `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :safari)`)
- I've checked the file's permissions and made them as permissive as possible (`-rwxrwxrwx`)
- I can upload the same file and submit it without problem outside of the test (i.e. in my development environment)
- I get the same error with other files (including an image)
- I get the same error if I move the file to a different location (like `/tmp`)

Based on the above, I *think* the problem is that (for some reason) Chrome can't access the file or some security/privacy setting is blocking access to the file. But so far I can't fathom what that reason is or how to find out or overcome it ...

Any ideas/help much appreciated! ‍♂️

UPDATE: The error doesn't happen when the tests run in a Github Action (on `ubuntu-latest`). So it's a case of "doesn't work on my machine" . Not sure this helps understand why I can't run the tests locally...

Comment: Well, I still don't know the answer to the question (_why_ is this error happening), but after a lot of trial and error I stumbled on steps that get the tests passing.
1. Run the spec that attempts to upload the file but comment out `attach_file` - instead pause with `byebug`.
2. Manually choose the file to upload when the spec pauses, then `continue` the spec.
3. Now re-add the `attach_file` and remove the `byebug`.
4. Run the spec and chrome allows Capybara to automatically upload the file.

I feel like maybe chrome is caching something when the file is manually uploaded?